# Empty node in cactus construction

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a necessary condition for not having empty node in the construction of the cactus of the minimum cuts of a graph? 
In particular is there a necessary condition for not having empty k-junction node with k>3?

Furthermore can someone suggest me a good book about cactus construction?

Thank you in advance.